# issue with highlight the cell border in tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.663 green:0.0 blue:0.373 alpha:1] CGColor]];                        
[cell.layer setBorderWidth:3.0];
```

the above code is higlighting the cell border when i select.
 when i am selecting another cell that cell also hightlight. so two cell are highlighted. I want to highlight the particular cell which i selected. 
 any one facing this issue give me the suggestion to me. 
@ thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Keep your selected cell in an instance variable. Then when a cell gets selected and if it's different than the one you kept in your instance variable, then un-highlight your instance variable's borders and highlight the newly selected cell's borders. And now assign this newly selected cell as your instance variable.